# Cannot update object value, keeps overwriting by strange id | javaScript Mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I couldn't update object value and figure out how...

The thing I wan to do is if the frequency is one time, return query with 'creatorDetails.uuid' and measureId.

```
hasCompleted(userId) {
  // ...
  const query = {
    'creatorDetails.uuid': userId,
    measureId: this._id,
  };

  if (this.typeOptions.frequency === Frequency.ONE_TIME) {
    return query;
    console.log('query - inside', query);
  }
  // ...
  console.log('query - outside', query);
  return MeasureData.find(query).count() > 0;
}
```

But this didn't work well.

`console.log('query - inside, query)` shows

```
{
  creatorDetails.uuid: "wD7BaeY6SsNSBgjbg"
  measureId: "RMLY8unSwSJtRDde2"
}
```

`console.log('query - outside, query)` shows

```
{
  creatorDetails.uuid: "wD7BaeY6SsNSBgjbg"
  measureId: "PPt4tnGNxW34F5o8t" 
}
```

So I tried below.

```
hasCompleted(userId) {
  // ...
  const query = {
    'creatorDetails.uuid': userId,
    measureId: this._id,
  };

  if (this.typeOptions.frequency === Frequency.ONE_TIME) {
    // query.creatorDetails.uuid = userId; // this cause an error as well
    query.measureId = this._id; // added
    console.log('query - inside', query);
  }
  // ...
  console.log('query - outside', query);
  return MeasureData.find(query).count() > 0;
}
```

`console.log('query - inside', query)` shows the same

```
{
  creatorDetails.uuid: "wD7BaeY6SsNSBgjbg"
  measureId: "RMLY8unSwSJtRDde2"
}
```

`console.log('query - outside', query)` shows also the same

```
{
  creatorDetails.uuid: "wD7BaeY6SsNSBgjbg"
  measureId: "PPt4tnGNxW34F5o8t" 
}
```

Somehow measureId gets overwrote by a strange measureId `PPt4tnGNxW34F5o8t`

I also tried `push` inside of `hasCompleted()`

```
if (this.typeOptions.frequency === Frequency.ONE_TIME) {
  query.measureId.push(this._id)
}
```

But I got an error saying `query.measureId.push id not a function`

Does anybody know how to update query?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the code:

You have to console first and then return otherwise it won't call the `console.log` because of unreachable statement

```
hasCompleted(userId) {
  // ...
  const query = {
    'creatorDetails.uuid': userId,
    measureId: this._id,
  };

  console.log(this.typeOptions.frequency, Frequency.ONE_TIME, this.typeOptions.frequency === Frequency.ONE_TIME);
  if (this.typeOptions.frequency === Frequency.ONE_TIME) {

    console.log('query - inside', query);
    return query; // you have return after doing the console
  }
  // ...
  console.log('query - outside', query);
  return MeasureData.find(query).count() > 0;
}
```

Can you try this and let me know if there is any change in output or not?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually tried your suggestion earlier but the outcome was the error massage on code editor ```Unreachable code detected``` and there was no console log for ```query - inside```. So I believe ```query - inside``` need to be before ```return query```

Comment: No console log means the control is not executing the `if` condition. So, there is a chance where the `if` condition results in false. I have updated the code try it once. 
It would be nice if you can share the message you are getting with the stack trace?